# Do the two manifolds intersect at a submanifold

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose now I have two smooth manifolds of dimension $n-1$, which are given by the zero level sets of two polynomials. Specifically, suppose $M$ is the manifold given by the zero set of the **polynomial** $p_1: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $N$ is the manifold given by the zero set of the **polynomial** $p_2: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. $n\ge 2$. Suppose $M$ and $N$ are different and each of them only have one connected component. **I am wondering is it possible that the two manifolds intersect at a submanifold of dimension also $n-1$?**

Probably the statement of the question is not hundred percent correct, since I think the intersection might not be a submanifold. But what I want to ask is that is it possible that two curves defined by the zero level set of two polynomials share a common part(sub-arc)? Is it possible that two surfaces given by the zero level sets of two polynomials share a common part (a sub-surface)? And also the cases for higher dimensional manifolds. Again, the zero level set do not contain any critical points.

Note: By regular value theorem, we have that to let the zero level set be a manifold, we require that the level set do not contain any critical point. So, $M$ and $N$ do not have any critical point.

Comment: You can do a sphere inside an other sphere which intersect only at one point I think

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your reply. I think I did not ask the right question that I really want to ask. I updated the question. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your edited question does have a positive answer. Try to prove this first when $n=2$ using the Bezout theorem.

Comment: Hi Moishe, thanks for your reply. When $n=2$, I know that it is impossible to have two such different curves. Since bezout’s inequality implies that the curves can only intersect at finitely many points. Otherwise, they must be the same or have a common factor. But i am wondering is there a same conclusion in higher dimensional spaces. Since when $n>2$, if you want use bezout, you will need three polynomials. But we only have two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is very possible. Consider, for example, the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and the parabola $y=x^2-\frac54$. You can make higher-dimensional examples quite easily.

**EDIT** (responding to the totally different question): With polynomials or real analytic functions, this cannot happen unless the hypersurfaces coincide (at least on a connected component). However, in the smooth category, you can use bump functions to create two hypersurfaces that coincide on a large (closed) subset (with interior) and then diverge. Note that they will coincide on a manifold with boundary. If you require that the set of coincidence have no boundary, then they'll have to agree on a whole connected component, of course.

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks very much for your answer. But I think I asked a question that not really the one I want know. I updated the question. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: That's now a very different question. See my edit.

Comment: I think the preferred style on MSE is to post a new question when the question changes so radically. But, no problem this time!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it is also impossible. But I do not know how to show it. I first want to use "identity theorem" to show the conclusion. But to use "identity theorem", I need to have an open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (for the surface case) so that the function value is same on the open set. But I cannot find such an open set, which stops me proving the conclusion by using identity theorem. It would be better if you can provide some idea on how to show the result.

Comment: No, it's deeper than that. In the complex setting, it's the Weierstrass Preparation Theorem which generalizes the facts we know for polynomial rings.

Comment: Hi Ted, I saw you added the comments "they will coincide on a manifold with boundary. If you require that the set of coincidence have no boundary, then they'll have to agree on a whole connected component". May I ask how could you get this?